# Resetting Layer Extent in MXD file using ArcObjects and C#?

Tags: arcobjects, layers, c#, extents

When I change data source properties of a layer using ArcObjects in C#, I lose the extent set for that layer.
How can I reset the layer extent?

Below is the code in which I am resetting database connection properties for a layer causing to loose layer extent values like top, left, bottom, right.

```
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer layer = pLayer;

            var dataLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IDataLayer)layer;
            var datasetName = (IDatasetName)dataLayer.DataSourceName;
            var newWorkspaceName = (IWorkspaceName)((IDataset)targetWorkspace).FullName;

            datasetName.WorkspaceName = newWorkspaceName;
            dataLayer.DataSourceName = (IName)datasetName; ;
            layer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer)dataLayer;
```

Comment: Does the feature class you're repointing the feature layer to have a valid extent? There is a method to recalculate the extent of a feature class in IFeatureClassManage http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureClassManage_Interface/0025000002s1000000/ which is implemented by IFeatureClass i.e. ((dataLayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass as IFeatureClassManage).UpdateExtent() which should refresh the extent of the feature class in your IFeatureLayer.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I added the following code but featureClass.Extent throws an exception. ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)layer;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClassManage featureClassManage = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClassManage)featureClass;
            featureClassManage.UpdateExtent();

Comment: @MichaelStimson, i get this message in Extent property of my current layer featureclass : Extent = '((ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IGeoDataset)(featureClass)).Extent' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Comment: That's odd, what type of data storage is your feature class?

Comment: @MichaelStimson, It does not have a specific featureclass. Under source section in ArcMAp for this layer, it says "FeatureType" as "Simple" and "GeometryType" as "Polygon"

Comment: How is this possible? an object must implement IFeatureClass to be the featureclass of an IFeatureLayer... but you're using IDataLayer which is different, what kind of data is it? To implement FeatureType =  esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple and ShapeType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon your object should also implement IFeatureClass - even if it's an in_memory, XY Event layer etc.

Comment: Did you try setting `ILayer2.AreaOfInterest` ?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall,Yes i did but still in ArcMap, top, bottom, left, right are shown blank. Do i have to save .MXD file and than check layer properties instead of checking properties at runtime, to find out if layer properties actually changed?